# функция getCountOfOddNumbers не работает с отрицательными параметрами

Tags: javascript

Подскажите где ошибся  в функции. Условие было : (Returns count of odd numbers from zero to the resulting number. The resulting number is taken into account.) 
example:

- 4  => 2
- -5  => 3
- 10 => 5
- -15 => 8

Проблема в том что моя функция не работает как надо с отрицательными параметрами - возвращает 0

```js
function getCountOfOddNumbers(number) {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i <= number; i += 1) {
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
console.log(getCountOfOddNumbers(-5))
```

Comment: Но зачем цикл? А если я вам задам число `9007199254740991` сколько вы считать будете?

Comment: Напиши пожалуйста  свой вариант без цикла

Comment: `Math.ceil(Math.abs(number)/2)`

Comment: Благодарю, до этого  варианта я не додумался

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас значение `number` меньше 0. Итераций просто нет

```js
function getCountOfOddNumbers(number) {
  let count = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i <= Math.abs(number); i += 1) {
    if (i % 2 !== 0) {
      count += 1;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
console.log(getCountOfOddNumbers(-5))
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь !